# What is the correct way of using the map while getting the last update record from the list of object

Tags: java, performance

What is the difference between the below two approach of getting the last updated record from the list and which one is better and why?

Example -
Assume List of Message contains the record in sequence where Message object would be:

```
Message
{
   Integer id ;
   String name ;
}
```

and value in the list called "messages" contains

```
[1 , "a"],[2, "b"],[1 , "b"],[1, "c"]
```

result should contain only these two record -

```
[2, "b"] ,[1, "c"]
```

Solution1 -

```
Map<Integer,String> latestMessage = new HashMap<>();
             for (Message m : messages) { 
                 latestMessage.put(m.getId(), m.getName());
             }
```

Solution 2 -

```
Map<Integer,String> latestMessage = new HashMap<>();
            for (Message m : messages) { 
                         if(!latestMessage.containsKey(m.getId())) {
                         latestMessage.put(m.getId(), m.getName());
                         }
                         else {
                             latestMessage.replace(m.getId(), m.getName())  ;
                         }
                     }
```

Comment: Solution 2 does two lookups for each id: once in containsKey() and a second time in either put() or replace(). Solution 1 only does one lookup. By the way, it's `Map<Integer, String>` not `Map<String, Message>`.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the former (`put`) since you are not using the message or even trying to *merge* (I put emphasis on that because of Java 8 and [`merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method):

You don't do stuff like that either:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = ...;
for (Message m : messages)
  map.computeIfAbsent(m.getId(), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(m.getName());
```

And if you were, you should probably use `Stream` and `groupingBy` as in:

```
messages.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Message::getId, Message::getName));
```

Going back to your two use cases:

- Using `put` is also shorter and is easier to understand: the latter (`containsKey` + `put`/`replace`) will be harder to understand (not **that** harder, but still, you'll have to read the code to understand it).
- In terms of performance, using `put` should be a bit faster than checking if mapping exist because you do a little bit more operation. I would not put my hand on fire for that, but you will have to write a benchmark (using JMH) to compare which is better.

**TL;DR:** use put unless you can prove that `containsKey` + `put`/`replace` is better.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code to see the performance difference between the approaches you've given:

```java
public class MapPerformanceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap();
        // fill the map with 50000 entities
        int count = 50000;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            // value doesn't matter
            map.put(i, getRandom(0, count));
        }
        // fill a set with one million entities
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet();

        int setSize = 1000000;
        for (int i = 0; i < setSize; i++) {
            set.add(getRandom(0, count));
        }

        // use the set to test performance
        long startTime = System.nanoTime(), endTime = 0;
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = set.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            int next = iterator.next();
            map.put(next, getRandom(0, count));
        }
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(String.format("PUT: %d", endTime - startTime));

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        iterator = set.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            int next = iterator.next();
            if(!map.containsKey(next)) {
                map.put(next, getRandom(0, count));
            }
            else {
                map.replace(next, getRandom(0, count))  ;
            }
        }
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(String.format("REPLACE: %d", endTime - startTime));
    }

    private static int getRandom(int min, int max) {
        return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
    }
}
```

When running the above code, it prints on console the following:

```
PUT: 17171025
REPLACE: 18274190
```

Which means the first approach has slightly a better performance.